# Arithmetic operation with SELECT statements in Impala

Tags: mysql, hiveql, impala

I am writing a query that needs to GROUP BY the type of a row, and divide the value by the total to know the % of total in IMPALA.
Ex.:

```
Name                           performance
something type1 something           15
something type1 something           18
something type2 something           23
something something something       345
something type2 something           23

SELECT
CASE WHEN name like '%type1%' then 'type 1'
    WHEN name like '%type2%' then 'type2'
    ELSE 'other' END as type
,sum(performance) / (SELECT sum(performance) FROM table)
FROM table
GROUP BY type
```

This gives me an error of AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the select list.
Can anyone advise how would I approach this problem?

Comment: I don't understand if you are really extracting from same table: `sum(performance) / (SELECT sum(performance) FROM table)
FROM table`

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs only "()"

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN name like '%type1%' then 'type 1'
    WHEN name like '%type2%' then 'type2'
    Else 'other' END) as type
,sum(performance) / (SELECT sum(performance) FROM table)
FROM Table
GROUP BY type
```